# Symfony ORM Doctrine, database created but not displayed in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, ubuntu, orm, doctrine, symfony

I'm currently trying, for the first time, to use the ORM doctrine in Symfony3. I created the database with "php bin/console doctrine:database:create". The database is created, but nothing is displayed in phpmyadmin. Is it normal ?

Comment: As long as youre using the same user you should have access to (see) the same databases

Comment: So do you know where could be the problem ?

Comment: Is the database not displayed at all, or is it empty ?

Comment: I finally created the whole database by hand. And it works. I still didn't understand why the db is not created automatically with the terminal, but nevermind...